# Have a multi-ip interface. How to select one of them to establish an outgoing connection?

Tags: sockets, select, ip, local, sctp

I am working with with an interface with multiple assigned IP addresses.
I need establish a connection from this interface to a remote listening SCTP socket (not in multi-homing mode).

How is it possible to select the desired interface's IP as the source of the connection?
What flag/socket-option should be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `bind()` function to set the local IP address.

Comment: Ok,dumb question for a dumb socket programmer :)

Comment: Just specify port `0` when you call `bind()` to let the kernel still choose the source port.